# Multilanguage express app

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I wonder what would be the best way to implement multiple versions / languages of the same content in the same layout in express.

Should I just do this?

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render(language + "/index");
});
```

Or is there a smarter / better way?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I would suggest to keep only one template, as if you use one template per language it will get out of hand very quickly, let alone duplicate much content (and the small amount of "logic" you would put in a template too). Many applications use a tool called gettext to do the internationalization thing. There is a node.js library for it at https://github.com/DanielBaulig/node-gettext

Alternatively there is also [i18n-node](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node). It appears to have a bit more integration with express js.

Answer (score 13):

The [i18n-node](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node) is the simplest and greatest module that you should use. You can use directly in Javascript code or with Jade/Handlebar templates  with express js.

Why should you use i18n?

- Auto detection of locale from the browser by header, cookie or query parameter depending on your setup.
- It comes with examples as well.
- It automatically generates a `en.json` by default inside `./locales/`. This acts as a master file for you to start building new translations.
- Supports  Singular and plural forms
- Support for parameters: `__('Hello %s', 'Marcus')` returns `Hallo Marcus`

Answer (score 6):

i thought that we can define json objects in lang folder like , en.js , fr.js and this json files contains  key value pairs than render to template according to user's language setting , lang settings can be into database.

And we can save this fr.js or anything else into res.locals for calling every template .

Is this suitable?