# Multilingual blog with Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

good morning.

My whole site is based on Node.Js and I'm developing the blog for this site, I'm interested in doing it in English, Spanish and Portuguese, both the site and the blog.

I'm using: node.js, mongodb, express and react.js

I'm interested for example that the URLs are like this:

```
mysite.com/en/contact/
mysite.com/pt/blog/my-article-here/
mysite.com/es/blog/mi-articulo-aqui/
```

What could you recommend?

Comment: What is your question? You seem to have a clear idea of what url structure you want.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? Do you want to be able to serve those urls, or do you want automatic translation?

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting, I really appreciate it.

I don't want to do the translation automatically, I want to write my blog posts in different languages and leave them in URLs like the ones I'm giving in the example.

mysite-com/en/blog/blog-post/
mysite-com/es/blog/publicacion-blog/

What would be the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 options:

- or you can do it on the back end: https://phrase.com/blog/posts/node-js-i18n-guide/
- or you can do on the front end: https://github.com/Irrelon/jquery-lang-js

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what modules you are using on nodejs app here is another post that may aid:

[Multilanguage express app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866778/multilanguage-express-app)

But the very basic functionality is the template you serve from node js will change depending on the URL. Depending on if you are going to translate each page manually or use a third-party module as https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node will normally decide how you move ahead with this.